# C++: Scons error: "ambiguous overload"

Tags: c++

I hope someone can help me get jsonrpc-cpp to compile. (http://jsonrpc-cpp.sourceforge.net/)

When I type `scons` as per the documentation, I get:

```
eamorr@Compaq6000:~/Desktop/jsonrpc-cpp$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o src/jsonrpc_handler.os -c -std=c++98 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Werror -O2 -fPIC src/jsonrpc_handler.cpp
src/jsonrpc_handler.cpp: In member function ‘bool Json::Rpc::Handler::Process(const std::string&, Json::Value&)’:
src/jsonrpc_handler.cpp:208:25: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator[]’ in ‘root[i]’
/usr/local/include/json/value.h:322:14: note: candidates are: Json::Value& Json::Value::operator[](Json::Value::ArrayIndex)
/usr/local/include/json/value.h:329:14: note:                 Json::Value& Json::Value::operator[](int)
/usr/local/include/json/value.h:334:20: note:                 const Json::Value& Json::Value::operator[](Json::Value::ArrayIndex) const
/usr/local/include/json/value.h:339:20: note:                 const Json::Value& Json::Value::operator[](int) const
src/jsonrpc_handler.cpp:213:23: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator[]’ in ‘response[j]’
/usr/local/include/json/value.h:322:14: note: candidates are: Json::Value& Json::Value::operator[](Json::Value::ArrayIndex)
/usr/local/include/json/value.h:329:14: note:                 Json::Value& Json::Value::operator[](int)
/usr/local/include/json/value.h:334:20: note:                 const Json::Value& Json::Value::operator[](Json::Value::ArrayIndex) const
/usr/local/include/json/value.h:339:20: note:                 const Json::Value& Json::Value::operator[](int) const
scons: *** [src/jsonrpc_handler.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Here is `src/jsonrpc_handler.cpp` (I've marked lines 208 and 213):

```
/*
 *  JsonRpc-Cpp - JSON-RPC implementation.
 *  Copyright (C) 2008-2011 Sebastien Vincent <sebastien.vincent@cppextrem.com>
 *
 *  This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
 *  along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

/**
 * \file jsonrpc_handler.cpp
 * \brief JSON-RPC server processor engine.
 * \author Sebastien Vincent
 */

#include "jsonrpc_handler.h"

namespace Json
{

  namespace Rpc
  {

    CallbackMethod::~CallbackMethod()
    {
    }

    Handler::Handler()
    {
      /* add a RPC method that list the actual RPC methods contained in the Handler */
      Json::Value root;

      root["description"] = "List the RPC methods available";
      root["parameters"] = Json::Value::null;
      root["returns"] = "Object that contains description of all methods registered";

      AddMethod(new RpcMethod<Handler>(*this, &Handler::SystemDescribe, std::string("system.describe"), root));
    }

    Handler::~Handler()
    {
      /* delete all objects from the list */
      for(std::list<CallbackMethod*>::const_iterator it = m_methods.begin() ; it != m_methods.end() ; it++)
      {
        delete (*it);
      }
      m_methods.clear();
    }

    void Handler::AddMethod(CallbackMethod* method)
    {
      m_methods.push_back(method);
    }

    void Handler::DeleteMethod(const std::string& name)
    {
      /* do not delete system defined method */
      if(name == "system.describe")
      {
        return;
      }

      for(std::list<CallbackMethod*>::iterator it = m_methods.begin() ; it != m_methods.end() ; it++)
      {
        if((*it)->GetName() == name)
        {
          delete (*it);
          m_methods.erase(it);
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    bool Handler::SystemDescribe(const Json::Value& msg, Json::Value& response)
    {
      Json::Value methods;
      response["jsonrpc"] = "2.0";
      response["id"] = msg["id"];

      for(std::list<CallbackMethod*>::iterator it = m_methods.begin() ; it != m_methods.end() ; it++)
      {
        methods[(*it)->GetName()] = (*it)->GetDescription();
      }

      response["result"] = methods;
      return true;
    }

    std::string Handler::GetString(Json::Value value)
    {
      return m_writer.write(value);
    }

    bool Handler::Check(const Json::Value& root, Json::Value& error)
    {
      Json::Value err;

      /* check the JSON-RPC version => 2.0 */
      if(!root.isObject() || !root.isMember("jsonrpc") || root["jsonrpc"] != "2.0") 
      {
        error["id"] = Json::Value::null;
        error["jsonrpc"] = "2.0";

        err["code"] = INVALID_REQUEST;
        err["message"] = "Invalid JSON-RPC request.";
        error["error"] = err;
        return false;
      }

      if(root.isMember("id") && (root["id"].isArray() || root["id"].isObject()))
      {
        error["id"] = Json::Value::null;
        error["jsonrpc"] = "2.0";

        err["code"] = INVALID_REQUEST;
        err["message"] = "Invalid JSON-RPC request.";
        error["error"] = err;
        return false;
      }

      /* extract "method" attribute */
      if(!root.isMember("method") || !root["method"].isString())
      {
        error["id"] = Json::Value::null;
        error["jsonrpc"] = "2.0";

        err["code"] = INVALID_REQUEST;
        err["message"] = "Invalid JSON-RPC request.";
        error["error"] = err;
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    }

    bool Handler::Process(const Json::Value& root, Json::Value& response)
    {
      Json::Value error;
      std::string method;

      if(!Check(root, error))
      {
        response = error;
        return false;
      }

      method = root["method"].asString();

      if(method != "")
      {
        CallbackMethod* rpc = Lookup(method);
        if(rpc)
        {
          return rpc->Call(root, response);
        }
      }

      /* forge an error response */
      response["id"] = root.isMember("id") ? root["id"] : Json::Value::null;
      response["jsonrpc"] = "2.0";

      error["code"] = METHOD_NOT_FOUND;
      error["message"] = "Method not found.";
      response["error"] = error;

      return false;
    }

    bool Handler::Process(const std::string& msg, Json::Value& response)
    {
      Json::Value root;
      Json::Value error;
      bool parsing = false;

      /* parsing */
      parsing = m_reader.parse(msg, root);

      if(!parsing)
      {
        /* request or batched call is not in JSON format */
        response["id"] = Json::Value::null;
        response["jsonrpc"] = "2.0";

        error["code"] = PARSING_ERROR;
        error["message"] = "Parse error.";
        response["error"] = error; 
        return false;
      }

      if(root.isArray())
      {
        /* batched call */
        size_t i = 0;
        size_t j = 0;

        for(i = 0 ; i < root.size() ; i++)
        {
          Json::Value ret;
          Process(root[i], ret);   //line 208!

          if(ret != Json::Value::null)
          {
            /* it is not a notification, add to array of responses */
            response[j] = ret;   //line 213!
            j++;
          }
        }
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return Process(root, response);
      }
    }

    bool Handler::Process(const char* msg, Json::Value& response)
    {
      std::string str(msg);

      return Process(str, response);
    }

    CallbackMethod* Handler::Lookup(const std::string& name) const
    {
      for(std::list<CallbackMethod*>::const_iterator it = m_methods.begin() ; it != m_methods.end() ; it++)
      {
        if((*it)->GetName() == name)
        {
          return (*it);
        }
      }

      return 0;
    }

  } /* namespace Rpc */

} /* namespace Json */
```

I'm really hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

Many thanks in advance,

---

Edit: Here's what I did on lines 208 and 213:

Process(root[(Json::Value::ArrayIndex)i], ret);   //line 208

response[(Json::Value::ArrayIndex)j] = ret;   //line 213

Comment: Uh, I don't know, report it to the developer?

Comment: Try casting to `Json::Value::ArrayIndex` at lines 208 and 213. Or just submit a bug report.

Comment: If you are not the developer (you are not, right?) and as long as you can report a bug (it's open source, right?), just report a bug. And if you can, try compiling it with different version of the compiler.

Comment: @Jan Hudec: Alternatively/Additionally, if one is kind enough, a fix might be passed in.

Comment: @kbok - that worked! Woop! Woop!

Comment: @Eamorr: Why can't you use one of the supported index types, `int` or `ArrayIndex`? I doubt you need an explicit cast.

Comment: @Eamorr: I would downvote you even more just for ignoring attempts to help you.

Comment: I just find it dubious to declare types as `XXX` when you must `static_cast<YYY>()` them anyway. Why not declare them YYY right away and follow the API? Or, as in "grow up", be mature enough to post a bug-report to the developers who kindly sacrificed their time for ppl like you. But nope, you act like a rascal, chose the first answer that fit, leaft this question and ignored others, because it magically works for you now. This isn't something anyone mature would consider mature. But, now that you've silenced the compiler and given him full permission to truncate away information, sleep well.

Comment: Note that this wasn't beggary to accept my answer, but rather targetted at my comment that you so far ignored. The last fat answer was an one for your comment to "grow up". Anyways, I hope we can leave the day not in anger ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `operator[]`  expects either `int`  or `Json::Value::ArrayIndex`, you should pass one of those instead of a `size_t`. I guess that `ArrayIndex` is a signed type, too, or `sizeof(size_t)>sizeof(ArrayIndex)`, so there is no good conversion of `size_t` to either `int` or `ArrayIndex`, therefore it is ambiguous.

Maybe post a suggestion to the developers or find out about the motivation for not using the more idiomatic `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

On line 208

```
Process(root[i], ret);   //line 208!
```

the compiler says that `i` can be either `int` or `Json::Value::ArrayIndex` (but it is size_t).

From what I can find about Json, the index could be

```
typedef unsigned int ArrayIndex;
```

And on your machine `size_t` obviously doesn't match that. Perhaps it is `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`?

In that case I think it can be time for a bug report about missing portability.